# Using "after" with a period of time specified right after it

Tags: grammar, prepositions, subordinate-clauses

Do I need to turn a period of time into a dependent clause subject when I use the preposition "after" right in front of it or is it not necessary?

For example, can I just say:

> I would only see him shortly after each class when I was already
>   leaving.

Or do I have to say:

> I would only see him shortly after each class **was over** when I was
>   already leaving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct, but the first is shorter and sounds more natural to me.  You don't have to say "*was over*", because "***after*** class" already implies that the class was over.